# SharePoint 2013 Service Reference Alerts Through /_vti_bin/alerts.asmx

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, sharepoint

[I found a resource for getting Alert information in SharePoint 2010 through Service References](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/get-alerts-from-sharepoint-2010-site-using-web-service/), however I am working with a SP 2013 environment and the "Alerts" class no longer exists in the Service Reference.

I get the below compilation error when compiling the code in Visual Studio:

```
The namespace Alerts does not exist
The namespace CredentialCache does not exist
```

Does anyone have any examples for using the Alerts web service with SharePoint 2013? [The MS resource here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/alerts.alerts.getalerts(v=office.12).aspx) is not very descriptive and doesn't help me with CredentialCache also not compiling.